# How to get a pageable result for an aggregation with MongoOperations?

Tags: mongodb, pagination, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I am using the Aggregation-API and pass my aggregation (some grouping etc.) to

```
MongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, ...)
```

But i can not find an operation how to get a Pageable result for the query.
I can include sort, skip and limit to the aggregation to create the page by hand but i am missing the total query size here.

Is there a better way to get a pageable result for the aggregation than to execute a previous count-query which counts exactly the same as the aggregation without skip and limit?

I would like to write something like

```
MongoOperations.aggregate(aggregation, MyClass.class, MyClass.class, pageable)
```

Comment: Agregation pipelines are not "pageable" like normal query cursors. The `$skip` and `$limit` are implemented as "pipeline stages" and the pipeline results cannot be modifed in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB returns as a result of a aggregation a single document. It also uses a single document for the intermediate results for each stage during the aggregation.

So i don't think you can page through the result because it's only one document. Perhaps you can keep the result in memory in your application because MongoDB documents (and thus aggreation results) are guaranteed to be smaller than 16 MB.